# How do I send a message to a Native View hosted by PlatformViewLink?

Tags: flutter

Looking at the documentation for `PlatformViewLink` and `AndroidViewController`, there doesn't seem to be any way of sending custom messages to the native view. How can this be achieved ?

I suppose the intended solution is to use a `MethodChannel` in conjunction, but I'd like to be sure there are no alternative before I build that.